# How to refer html or text in delegate in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While using `delegate` I use to refer the id by:

```
$( "#suggestions" ).delegate( ".place", "click", function() {
    var thisId = this.id;
});
```

But how can I refer the html or text inside the element? Like: (Does Not Work)

```
var thisPlaceX = this.html;
```

See Line 36 and below of this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byfjj/1/). Here I am trying to:

- Type a keyword and suggest places
- Save Selected suggestion
- Delete saved suggestion on click

Comment: Note that [`delegate` has been deprecated in favour for `on`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) since v1.7. If you're using a more recent version you might consider migrating your code.

Comment: @Andy Thanks. I am thinikng of migrating asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var thisPlaceX = $( this ).html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$(this).html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`this.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated, but unless you're using JQ <= 1.6, use `on` instead of the deprecated `delegate`.

You're missing two things:

1. You need `this` to be a jQuery object, and
2. `html` is a function reference, `html()` *calls* the function, which is what you want.